# Android and iOS gcm instanceID

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

Different behaviors on iOS and Android

We have been trying to implement GCM on Android and iOS but there is a discrepancy on behaviors with the instanceID.

On Android and iOS when we request an instance ID every time we register our app we get the same token, this is true if we do not uninstall and install the app again, if we do that, we have a new instance ID on both, but the old android token becomes NOT_REGISTER and the old one on iOS is still working, leaving us to send 1 message the same Android device (ok) and 2 messages for the same iOS device (not ok)

Shouldn't the old iOS instanceID be NOT_REGISTER like it happens on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the old Instance ID will be invalidated as well. However if you generate a new Instance ID you should replace the old one with the new one and stop sending to the old one. Also if you send to the old one, you should get a canonical id in the response indicating which token to use instead of the old one you just used.

Comment: That's the behavior we are having with Android, with iOS we cant get a canonical id and the time that the old instance id on iOS takes to invalidate is bigger than the on in Android